# How can I save my dying palm tree?

Tags: trees, tree-care, fertilizer, palm

My palm tree started to become yellow in the last couple of months and I don't see any improvement. I've tried with some spike fertilizers for palm trees, but didn't seem to help. Here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is it ok to [cut off the first 3" at the top](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0LxJgQSFpg) to remove the damaged area and promote new growth? What should I do to help?

I'm in the Pacific Northwest, and the palm is outdoors, in open ground.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, don't cut off the top 3 inches of the palm - its equivalent to decapitation in an animal, and the plant will die. You can try removing anything that's dead though. This palm looks to be a [*Trachycarpus fortunei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trachycarpus_fortunei), and they are pretty hardy, but you haven't said and I'm not 100% certain without seeing more of it. What's interesting is the fasciation that seems to be going on - have you had unusual cold in the last few months, such that the palm won't have experienced before?

I can see some green leaves, but can't tell how many are left, so a picture of the whole plant might be useful - also check the base and trunk of the tree - you're looking for soft, soggy areas or weeping or rotting.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0LxJgQSFpg) suggests cutting as an option. Yes, it was a harder winter this year, but the other palms in the area don't seem to be that affected. Haven't noticed any rotten areas on the trunk though, so I hope there's still life in it. I'll upload more pics later today. Thanks!